# string.xml in Android library

Tags: java, android, xml

I am working in a library for android apps, and I am trying to use the string.xml to put some message in key points for the users.

My problem is when I test the library in an android testing app to see the workflow and reach the point where am I displaying a message (in this case in the logs) that occurs a fatal error and the app crash.

I am thinking that collide with the `string.xml` from the testing app and overwrite the `string.xml` that I have in the library. Can this be solved in some way or I have forcibly use the testing app string.xml to workout with the library??

Do i have to make my class extends from Activity for use getResources()? or is any other way to get access to string.xml, I will leave the code and the logs.

Code

```
public void createCertificateLogTxt(){
    File certificado = new File (this.KeyFolderContainer.getAbsoluteFile(),"certificadoLog.txt");
    if(!certificado.exists()){
        try {
            certificado.createNewFile();
            this.CertificadoLog = certificado;
            Log.i(LOGFILE, "certificadoLog.txt Creado"+ this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOGFILE, "No se puede crear certificadoLog.txt"+ R.string.LOGFILE, e);
        }
    }
```

Logs

```
09-14 02:41:24.032: I/Choreographer(23748): Skipped 105 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-14 02:41:25.593: D/AndroidRuntime(23748): Shutting down VM
09-14 02:41:25.593: W/dalvikvm(23748): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    ... 11 more
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at com.idyseg.movilsecure.files.KeyFileManager.createCertificateLogTxt(KeyFileManager.java:76)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at com.idyseg.movilsecure.MSMasterControler.<init>(MSMasterControler.java:34)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at com.idyseg.librerytester.MainActivity.Conector(MainActivity.java:33)
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    ... 14 more
09-14 02:41:28.253: I/Process(23748): Sending signal. PID: 23748 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Which line is `KeyFileManager.java:76`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem -- or at least part of it -- is that you're trying to call `this.getResources()` during your Activity's constructor, as shown by this line in the stack trace:

```
09-14 02:41:25.753: E/AndroidRuntime(23748):    at com.idyseg.movilsecure.MSMasterControler.<init>(MSMasterControler.java:34)
```

As far as I know, the Resources are not available until the Activity's `onCreate` method has been called. Try moving the call to `createCertificateLogTxt` to your Activity's `onCreate` method.

Also, if you defined the `KeyFileManager` class as an Activity just so that you could invoke `getResources` on it, then that's also part of the problem: If it's not being *used* as an Activity (that is, if it doesn't use the standard Activity lifecyle methods), then once again the Resources won't be available through this class. In this case, you want to modify `KeyFileManager.createCertificateLogTxt()` to pass the main Activity's Context as a parameter:

```
KeyFileManager.createCertificateLogTxt(Context context) {
   //....
              Log.i(LOGFILE, "certificadoLog.txt Creado"+ context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
}
```

And by the way: although it's not important, this line:

```
        Log.e(LOGFILE, "No se puede crear certificadoLog.txt"+ R.string.LOGFILE, e);
```

looks suspicious to me; don't you want something like this?

```
        Log.e(LOGFILE, "No se puede crear certificadoLog.txt " + getString(R.string.LOGFILE), e);
```

Comment: the problem is this is not going  to work in activity at all, it is going to work as a thread in other class, the think is use the string.xml file but after i look a little, i concluded that is bad idea to work that way because a change of language in the device could make the library get confused about the file names and make the app crash, that is why i will discard this way of work, and use constans for do what i really need, finally i understand that i cant extends from activity class for use the resources to many thinks to control

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been asked few years back, but recently due to advancements in Android Studio, I found a more feasible solution.

When creating module, most of the time, we forget to update manifest of module, since we rarely use it when there is no `<activity>` present in our module for our use case. But, if we want to use a resource file like `strings.xml or drawables`, we need to define package in our Manifest, otherwise, we cannot use any resources in `res` directory of the module.

Like this,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.yourpackagename">      <!-- this line -->

</manifest>
```